# Аварийное завершение приложения без возникновения ошибки. Андроид

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Я создаю весьма простую 2d игру на андроид, используя libGDX.
После 5-10 минутного использования моего приложения оно просто вылетает без отображений ошибок в логах. Скорее всего это происходит из-за утечки памяти, так как я получаю много сообщений вроде
'GC_FOR_ALLOC'
'Grow heap (frag case)'
Причем я уничтожаю все ресурсы после использования, вызывая 'dispose' или присваивая ссылкам на объекты null. Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Как Вы думаете, сможет ли человек, который в глаза не видел Вашей программы, дать Вам полезную рекомендацию. "...Сталкивался ли кто-то с подобной проблемой?..." - ответ - безусловно много кто сталкивался

Comment: Leakcanary Вам в помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Всё было из-за того, что я забыл вызвать dispose() у пары текстур, обновлявшихся постоянно.